# ffmpeg: how add constant color margin to a video

Tags: ffmpeg

i have a video and i want to add a black background padding to top and bottom of the video to getting a square output.
[image]
is it possible to do this with `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the width is greater than the height,

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf pad=iw:iw:0:(oh-ih)/2:color=black -c:a copy out.mp4
```